# Why am i getting an extra line in my plotly plot?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe tx_user_type_revenue:
[image]

I create a plot using plotly but for some reason it shows me an extra line. This code works fine for other data.

[image]

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#filtering the dates and plot the result
tx_user_type_revenue = tx_user_type_revenue.query("InvoiceYearMonth > 201601 and InvoiceYearMonth < 201901")
plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=tx_user_type_revenue.query("UserType == 'Existing'")['InvoiceYearMonth'],
        y=tx_user_type_revenue.query("UserType == 'Existing'")['Revenue'],
        name = 'Existing'
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=tx_user_type_revenue.query("UserType == 'New'")['InvoiceYearMonth'],
        y=tx_user_type_revenue.query("UserType == 'New'")['Revenue'],
        name = 'New'
    )
]

plot_layout = go.Layout(
        xaxis={"type": "category"},
        title='New vs Existing Customers Revenue'
    )
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
pyoff.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Check your data, it is probably in there

Comment: The x-axis represents dates right ? I think that some of them are out of order. For example 201610 is followed by 201904. Try sorting the axis. I think this causes the problem

Comment: totally agree with @Jasmine, Try converting it to pd.to_datetime and then sort it.